# Renaming a mounted disc image

Tags: cocoa, diskimage, diskarbitration

The "source" below is a mounted disc image (dmg), named "New." I'm trying to rename it with a textField string and action. When I complete the action the rename fails and I am unable to eject it. The code works with standard files and folders.

Also - if I do a "Get Info" of the mounted disc image and rename it there, everything works fine.

Bottom line is I want to rename a mounted disc image using a textField string. Can someone explain?

```
NSString *source = [@"~/Desktop/New" stringByExpandingTildeInPath];
NSString *newFile = [input stringValue];
NSString *newPath = [[source stringByDeletingLastPathComponent] stringByAppendingPathComponent:newFile];
[[NSFileManager defaultManager] moveItemAtPath:source toPath:newPath error:NULL];
NSLog(@"File renamed to %@", newFile);
```

Comment: Are you trying to rename the disk image file or the volume inside the image?

Comment: It's shown on your desktop, but might not be mounted in `~/Desktop/`. Disk images, network shares and external drives are typically mounted in `/Volumes/`.

Answer (score 1):

You'll need to use the [disk arbitration framework](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/DriversKernelHardware/Conceptual/DiskArbitrationProgGuide/Introduction/Introduction.html).